# Executing Power Equations in Raster Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I am attempting to conduct a calculation in raster calculator, however I am coming up with numbers that I know are incorrect.

The equation I am attempting to execute is as follows: 
`84.146e-.00006x`

I have placed the above equation into raster calculator as follows:
`Power(84.146,(-.00006*"NortheastTerrain"))`

Where "NortheastTerrain" is the raster layer I am using to calculate.

How can I correct this error?

Comment: Can you post a properly formatted equation? http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/q/4162/2856